# Searching for multiple prefixes inside a column through Eloquent using RegEx

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a simple filtering tool, which allows users to filter profiles through different US states (Arizona, Alabama, and so on)

So I'm using the state's 2-character name in order to identify them internally.
A profile has a field called "linear_coverage", which is an imploded string of State + County where the profile is enabled.

For example, a profile could have the following "linear_coverage"

```
NY_Cattaraugus,NY_Chautauqua,NY_Erie,NY_Genesee,NY_Niagara,NY_Wyoming,NY_Cattaraugus,NY_Chautauqua,NY_Erie,NY_Genesee,NY_Niagara,NY_Wyoming,NY_Erie,NY_Niagara,NY_Erie,NY_Niagara,AK_Kodiak Island,AK_Skagway
```

You can see this person has New York (NY) and multiple counties selected, but it also has Alaska (AK).

So I've been trying to use the following:

```
foreach($states as $state)
    $query->orWhere('linear_coverages', 'LIKE', '%' . strtoupper($state) . '_%');
    //$query->orWhere('linear_coverages', 'regexp', strtoupper($state) . "_[A-z]+");
```

The second comment line was a test I ran, without having success.
I'm thinking, is there anyway for a RegEx to search for MULTIPLE prefixes inside a string?

So I could be search for [NY_,AK_] and this would return me the profile I just showed, and the other which meet the criteria.

Thanks a lot.
M.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out to how to achieve this

I replaced my Regexp by the following

```
/(NY|AZ)_[A-z]+/
```

By enclosing the different states and separating them with | symbol, the Regex will try to find any of these prefixes, and then the remaining string is valid.

I was able to filter down all my results properly. :D